# seq command unkown service or name

Tags: bash, command-substitution, kali-linux

```
    #!/bin/bash

    for ip in 'seq 1 254'; do
    ping -c 1 $0.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" &
    done
```

the file is ipsweep.sh
when i run it show me this

root@kali:ping: ./ipsweep.sh.seq: Name or service unkown

Answer (score 1):

First issue:

Replace `'seq 1 254'` with `$(seq 1 254)`.

If you replace both `'` with backticks it works too, but it's old syntax.

Second issue:

Replace `$0` with `$1` if you want to provide this part (192.168.1, e.g.) on the command line. `$0` contains name of your script.

Comment: it didn't work it kept showing the same result but thanks for your help

Comment: @R3d_F1lc0n It works for me with these changes; please check to make sure you've made the edits as recommended.